# I can insert images in to Salesforce RTF fields using copy and paste functionality in my org on IE or Chrome, other users can't

Tags: images, upload, chrome, internet-explorer, editor

A Salesforce specific Rich Text Field (I say Salesforce specific, because the RTF built in to Salesforce utilizes the Salesforce HTML editor so is assumed to have specific functionality pertaining to the Salesforce framework [source](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm)) in one of our organizations forms allows me to copy and paste images of varying sizes directly in from memory. I can do this on both Chrome and IE 11, both are currently updated to their latest versions - valid 14/06/2016.

I can do this with 5MB pictures and it will compress them to 1MB, or I can do it with < 1MB images. Size does not present an issue.

I've had complaints from numerous users who can't use the C+P functionality utilizing the Chrome browser. They also report that they can C+P in IE but it never actually presents itself and the loading icon spins out "forever" without any result (so they can't actually do it in IE).

I asked one of the users to reset chrome to factory defaults and test and he still couldn't do it.

Any ideas?

Thoughts much appreciated.

**PS** To those who marked this as being too generalized, in turn directing me to Stack Overflow, please let me know how you justify this as not being Salesforce specific. I'm happy to be wrong by the way!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iOBOAA2) under point threshold. The suggested workaround is this but that might/ might not work for certain users.

> Right click on the image in your browser and save the image to your
>   desktop, but this is also buggy and different browsers behave
>   differently (some allow you to right-click save, others do not) so
>   even the work around behavior is inconsistent.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, sorry if I made this seem like I was talking about copy and pasting from. I am talking about copy and pasting to the RTF. My users can't even get to that stage.